# Django login does not recognize the sent data

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, postgresql

I need help. I'm building a web application with Django and React. I'm working on the registration and login functionality, and so far the registration works well and creates a user in the database. However, when I try to log in, it always returns a 401 error, even though the user is in the database.

This is the Django code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.db import models


class Usuario_aplicacion(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        return check_password(raw_password, self.password)
```

views.py:

```
import bcrypt
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .UsuarioSerializer import UsuarioSerializer
from .models import Usuario_aplicacion


@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def registro(request):
    serializer = UsuarioSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        usuario = serializer.save()
        hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(usuario.password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
        usuario.password = hashed_password.decode('utf-8')
        usuario.save()
        return Response({'message': 'User created'}, status=201)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)


@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def login_user(request):
    username = request.data.get('username')
    password = request.data.get('password')
    try:
        usuario = Usuario_aplicacion.objects.get(username=username)
        if usuario.check_password(password):
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return Response({'success': True})
    except Usuario_aplicacion.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    return Response({'success': False}, status=401)
```

UsuarioSerializer.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework import serializers

from users.models import Usuario_aplicacion


class UsuarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario_aplicacion
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        usuario = Usuario_aplicacion(**validated_data)
        usuario.save()
        return usuario
```

and the form in react:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function LoginForm() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/apiusers/login/', {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.success) {
        setMessage('Login successful');
      } else {
        setMessage('Login failed');
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      setMessage('Login failed');
    });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{% csrf_token %}" />
      <label>
        Username:
        <input type="text" value={username} onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password:
        <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      {message && <div>{message}</div>}
    </form>
  );
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: you might want to share information on the authentication system you are using for DRF in your case, can you post your `settings.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last line in views.py to:

```py
return Response({'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid username or password'}, status=401)
```

I think it has to do with thefact that your Django view `login_user` isn't returning a response in case the authentication fails.

Also you might want to check to see if you accidentally mistyped your credentials.